# Преобразование строки в нижний регистр

Tags: c, c++

Подскажите функцию, которая преобразует строку в нижний регистр.

Comment: можешь обробувати кожен символ із строки функцією tolower()

Comment: це вже було казано

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вроде такой функции нет, можно пройти по всем символам строки, и к ним применить tolower(). Или вместо tolower() использовать добавить вычесть:

```
char A;
... //initialization
A = A - 'A' + 'a'; // tolower;
A = tolower(A); // tolower from ctype.h
```

Comment: "Добавить вычесть" - не понял идею. Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: добавить вычесть, основывается на ASCII кодах символов: если в A у нас содержится 'B', то отняв 'A' - получим 1, а потом прибавив 'a' получим 'b'. Ну это вообще на крайняк, если забыл что где лежит. И в случае с другими раскладками (к примеру кириллица) возникнут проблемы, так как их коды идут не под ряд.

Comment: А если лежит в чаре 'a', т.е. символ в нижнем регистре, то что в результате получится?

Comment: Ну для этого я всегда выполняю проверку 'A' <= A <= 'Z' ))) а то будет беда, что то в А получим, но точно не 'A'!

Comment: Угу, без этого никуда. Но лучше использовать стандартную функцию, которая будет делать то же самое. Как минимум сэкономите время.

Answer (score 7):

Есть функция tolower, которая переводит символы в нижний регистр. Можно применить ее ко всем символам строки:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <сctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s = "IaFFSjndsUFfE";
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), tolower);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Изящно и элегантно. Кстати, для С++ есть специальный рекомендованный хедер cctype

Comment: @skegg поменял, спасибо!

Comment: Красиво, но вызывает UB на отрицательных кодах символов. Нужен `std::transform(..., [](unsigned char c){return std::tolower(c)});`.

Answer (score 2):

Вряд ли toLower работает с русскими буквами.

Первый способ - создать массив и преобразовывать символы по нему:

```
char str[]="СтрОка, ПЕРЕвоДимая, В НИЖНИЙ РЕГИСТР.";
char[256] table={/*Эту таблицу надо заполнить вручную*/};
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(str)-1; i++)
    str[i]=table[str[i]];
```

Второй способ - использование разницы между маленькими и большими символами:

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(str)-1; i++)
{
    if(str[i]>'A' && str[i]<'Z') str[i]+='z'-'Z';
    if(str[i]>'А' && str[i]<'Я') str[i]+='я'-'Я';
}
```

Первый способ работает быстрее, если таблица предварительно заполнена.

Comment: По поводу tolower и русских букв - опропобал на лине. Действительно, не работает. Чтобы нормально преобразовывать, нужно создать строку wchar_t  и далее с нею работать функцией towlower из wchar.h

Answer (score 0):

Почарно можно при помощи функции tolower() из ctype.h

Answer (score 0):

> Этот код переводит в нижний регистр русские буквы

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251); 
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    vector <string> lc = { "а", "б", "в", "г", "д", "е", "ё", "ж", "з", "и", "й", "к", "л", "м", "н", "о", "п", "р", "с", "т", "у", "ф", "х", "ц", "ч", "ш", "щ", "э", "ю", "я" };
    vector <char> uc   = {'А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я'};
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= str.length() - 1; i++) {
        for (int u = 0; u <= uc.size() - 1; u++) {
            if (str[i] == uc[u]) {
                str.replace(i, 1 , lc[u]);
                

            }

        }

    }
    cout << str;
}
```