# Преобразование строки типа std::u16string к нижнему регистру

Tags: c++

Требуется преобразовать строку с кириллицей типа std::u16string к нижнему регистру.

Что пробовал:

```
1) boost::algorithm::to_lower

2) std::use_facet<std::ctype<char16_t>>(std::locale("")).tolower(&test[0],&test[0] + test.size());

3) std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), test.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Пробовал устанавливать перед этим локаль:

```
1) std::locale("");
2) std::locale("ru");
3) std::locale("RU");
4) std::locale("ru_RU"); - вызывается исключение
```

Во всех случаях результат преобразования строки u"Тест" равен: **"5ab**,
а должен быть: **тест**

При этом текст на латинице преобразуется правильно.
Строка с кириллицей типа std::wstring также преобразуется правильно.

Пример кода для воспроизведения:

```
std::locale("");
std::u16string test = u"Тест";
std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), test.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Условия воспроизведения:

ОС: Windows 7 64Bit Eng

Компилятор: Visual Studio 2017 Community

Кодировка файла с исходником: UTF-8 с BOM

Comment: Можно попробовать `setlocale (LC_ALL, ".OCP")` и вроде не нужно, но есть такая дериктива: `#pragma execute_character_set ("utf-16")`,  или `utf-8`, в зависимости от вашей кодировки файла, если текст переменной прописан в коде.

Comment: @user2134488 напишите рабочее решение в ответе, а не в вопросе

Comment: @NewView Попробовал ваш вариант, но не получилось. Получилось с использованием std::towlower (см. ответ ответ ниже). Так или иначе, спасибо!

Comment: _"Кодировка файла с исходником: UTF-8 с BOM"_ - вот мне кажется, что в этом месте фигня. Или компилятор умеет преобразовывать текст в другую кодировку при сборке?

Answer (score 3):

Поддержки Unicode в C++ нет(*), поэтому используйте сторонние средства. Одним из наиболее известных средств является [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org). Если собрать Boost с использованием ICU, то можно использовать Boost.Locale, которая может быть удобнее.

---

(*) Есть некоторые «ошмётки» Unicode в C++, но они не стоят внимания.

Comment: Увы, единственно верный ответ

Answer (score 1):

[Преобразование строки в нижний регистр](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/57388/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80), а также "По поводу tolower и русских букв - опропобал на лине. Действительно, не работает. Чтобы нормально преобразовывать, нужно создать строку wchar_t и далее с нею работать функцией towlower из wchar.h" – skegg 1 дек '11 в 14:56

Comment: А у меня под Linux towlower без преобразований, с типом std::u16string заработала. Хотя и не понятно почему. Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Пришел к такому рабочему решению:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cwctype>
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
std::u16string test = u"Тест";
std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), test.begin(), std::towlower);
return 0;
}
```

То есть использовать функцию **towlower**. Обязательно необходимо установить локаль.
Проверял под Ubuntu 14 (32-64), Mac OS Sierra, Windows Server 2008. 
В целом нет уверенности что это правильный подход, ведь в описании сказано, что функция towlower предназначена для обработки символов типа wchar_t, а у меня тип char16_t и под Linux wchar_t имеет размер 4 байта. Так или иначе работает. Если есть более правильное решение прошу делиться в ответах.

Answer (score -1):

Есть функция tolower, которая переводит символы в нижний регистр. Можно применить ее ко всем символам строки:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    std::string s = "IaFFSjndsUFfE";
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), tolower);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

специально для минусаторов

```
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <ctype.h>

    int main() {
        std::string s ="тест";
        std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), tolower);
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
```

рабочее решение

```
std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), test.begin(), ::towlower);
```

Проверял под Ubuntu 14 (32-64), Mac OS Sierra, Windows Server 2008. Везде работает.

специально для минусаторов

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    std::string s = "БОЛЬШИЕ РУСКИЕ БУКВЫ";
        std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::towlower); 

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Хоть чатик и почистили, код в ответе по-прежнему не даёт ответа на вопрос